# How to sort array of strings by function in shell script

Tags: bash, function, shell, sorting, gsutil

I have the following list of strings in shell script:

```
something-7-5-2020.dump
another-7-5-2020.dump
anoter2-6-5-2020.dump
another-4-5-2020.dump
another2-4-5-2020.dump
something-2-5-2020.dump
another-2-5-2020.dump
8-1-2021
26-1-2021
20-1-2021
19-1-2021
3-9-2020
29-9-2020
28-9-2020
24-9-2020
1-9-2020
6-8-2020
20-8-2020
18-8-2020
12-8-2020
10-8-2020
7-7-2020
5-7-2020
27-7-2020
7-6-2020
5-6-2020
23-6-2020
18-6-2020
28-5-2020
26-5-2020
9-12-2020
28-12-2020
15-12-2020
1-12-2020
27-11-2020
20-11-2020
19-11-2020
18-11-2020
1-11-2020
11-11-2020
31-10-2020
29-10-2020
27-10-2020
23-10-2020
21-10-2020
15-10-2020
23-09-2020
```

So my goal is to sort them by date, but it's in dd-mm-yyyy and d-m-yyyy format and sometimes there's a word before like word-dd-mm-yyyy. I would like to create a function to sort the values like any other language so it ignores the first word, casts the date to a common format and compares that format. In javascript it would be something like:

```
arrayOfStrings.sort((a, b) => functionToOrderStrings())
```

My code to obtain the array is the following:

```
dumps=$(gsutil ls gs://organization-dumps/ambient | sed "s:gs\://organization-dumps/ambient/::" | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's:/$::' | sort --reverse --key=3 --key=2 --key=1 --field-separator=-)
echo "$dumps"
```

I would like to say that I've already searched this in Stackoverflow and none of the answers did help me, because all of them are oriented to sort dates in correct format and that's not my case.

Comment: Use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: Silliness points for using `:` as the field delimiter in `sed` when your regex also contains `:`. There are two dozen other characters you could have picked which would have saved you from having to backslash the literal colon.

Comment: @FacundoYuffrida : You need to **define** how your input looks in general, not just give an **example**. For instance, could an entry be something like `foo12-08-2019.dump` too?

Comment: @user1934428 I gave the definition. It could be a date in dd-mm-yyyy format having d or dd and m or mm as day and month, or a word before that, always separated with hyphen. `foo12-08-2019.dump` can't be possible`. In spite of the definition, my question doesn't change because I ask how to use a function to sort, so I can do the function freely. My question is not about how to make the function, but how to insert a function in the sort.

Comment: kvothe838 : Sure, but what can come before or after that date in a string? You have the date in some context. You say foo12-08-2019.dump can not occur, although it clearly contains a date (12-08-2019). It's exacty for cases such as this, why a precise definition is neithed.

Comment: @kvothe838 : _ how to insert a function in the sort_ You ask about bash. Now, the bash language - different to languages such as _Ruby_ or _C++_, does not have a _sort_command. Hence it is meaningless to ask, how to insert a function there. Of course you can write your own function and then ask how to inject a sort function into it; but for this, you would have to first show the code of your sort function.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the results in a pipeline, involving an array seems completely superfluous here.

You can apply a technique called a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform): add a prefix to each line with a normalized version the data so it can be easily sorted, then sort, then discard the prefix.

I'm guessing something like the following;

```sh
gsutil ls gs://organization-dumps/ambient |
awk '{ sub("gs:\/\/organization-dumps/ambient/", "");
    if (! $0) next;
    sub("/$", "");
    d = $0;
    sub(/^[^0-9][^-]*-/, "", d);
    sub(/[^0-9]*$/, "", d);
    split(d, w, "-");
    printf "%04i-%02i-%02i\t%s\n", w[3], w[2], w[1], $0 }' |
sort -n | cut -f2-
```

In so many words, we are adding a tab-delimited field in front of every line, then sorting on that, then discarding the first field with `cut -f2-`.  The field extraction contains some assumptions which seem to be valid for your test data, but may need additional tweaking if you have real data with corner cases like if the label before the date could sometimes contain a number with dashes around it, too.

If you want to capture the result in a variable, like in your original code, that's easy to do; but usually, you should just run everything in a pipeline.

Notice that I factored your multiple `sed` scripts into the Awk script, too, some of that with a fair amount of guessing as to what the input looks like and what the `sed` scripts were supposed to accomplish. (Perhaps also note that `sed`, like Awk, is a scripting language; to run several `sed` commands on the same input, just put them after each other in the same `sed` script.)

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced that the `sub` entries are robust here. This might fail on a string `1foo-1-2-1984-bar`

Comment: Yeah, the regexes are almost certainly wrong if the sample is not completely representative.

Comment: The date seems always to be in front of the dot, so if you remove it combined with the trailing string, then the date is just located at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I didn't fully test it because I'm trying to understand what did you do, so I can make a white box test.

Answer (score 1):

1. Preprocess input to be in the format you want it to be for sorting.
2. Sort
3. Remove artifacts from step 1

The following:

```
sed -E '
   # extract the date and put it in first column separated by tab
   # this could be better, its just an example
   s/(.*-)?([0-9]?[0-9]-[0-9]?[0-9]-[0-9]{4})/\2\t&/;
   # If day is a single digit, add a zero in front
   s/^([0-9]-)/0\1/;
   # If month is a single digit, add a zero in front
   s/^([0-9][0-9]-)([0-9]-)/\10\2/
   # year in front? no idea - shuffle the way you want
   s/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\3-\2-\1/
' input.txt | sort | cut -f2-
```

outputs:

```
another-2-5-2020.dump
something-2-5-2020.dump
another-4-5-2020.dump
another2-4-5-2020.dump
anoter2-6-5-2020.dump
another-7-5-2020.dump
something-7-5-2020.dump
26-5-2020
28-5-2020
5-6-2020
7-6-2020
18-6-2020
23-6-2020
5-7-2020
7-7-2020
27-7-2020
6-8-2020
10-8-2020
12-8-2020
18-8-2020
20-8-2020
1-9-2020
3-9-2020
23-09-2020
24-9-2020
28-9-2020
29-9-2020
15-10-2020
21-10-2020
23-10-2020
27-10-2020
29-10-2020
31-10-2020
1-11-2020
11-11-2020
18-11-2020
19-11-2020
20-11-2020
27-11-2020
1-12-2020
9-12-2020
15-12-2020
28-12-2020
8-1-2021
19-1-2021
20-1-2021
26-1-2021
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
gsutil ls gs://organization-dumps/ambient | awk '{ match($0,/[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{4}/);dayt=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);split(dayt,map,"-");length(map[1])==1?map[1]="0"map[1]:map[1]=map[1];length(map[2])==1?map[2]="0"map[2]:map[2]=map[2];map1[mktime(map[3]" "map[2]" "map[1]" 00 00 00")]=$0 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for (i in map1) { print map1[i] }  }'
```

Explanation:

```
 gsutil ls gs://organization-dumps/ambient | awk '{ 
         match($0,/[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{4}/);             # Check that lines contain a date
         dayt=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);                                           # Extract the date
         split(dayt,map,"-");                                                      # Split the date in the array map based on "-" as the delimiter
         length(map[1])==1? map[1]="0"map[1]:map[1]=map[1];length(map[2])==1?map[2]="0"map[2]:map[2]=map[2];                                                        # Pad the month and day with "0" if required
         map1[mktime(map[3]" "map[2]" "map[1]" 00 00 00")]=$0                      # Get the epoch format date based on the values in the map array and use this for the index of the array map1 with the line as the value
       } 
   END { 
         PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";                                     # Set the ordering of the array
         for (i in map1) { 
            print map1[i]                                                          # Loop through map1 and print the values (lines)
         }  
        }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk, you can do this fairly easy:

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; FS="."}
     {n=split($1,t,"-"); a[t[n]*10000  + t[n-1]*100 + t[n-2]]=$0}
     END {for(i in a) print a[i]}' file
```

Essentially, we are asking GNU awk to traverse an array by index in ascending numeric order. Per line read, we extract the date. The date is always located before the <dot>-character and thus always in field 1 if the dot is the field separator (`FS="."`). We split the first field by the hyphen and use the total number of fields to extract the date. We convert the date simplistically to some number (`YYYY*10000+MM*100+DD`; `DD<100 && MM*100 < 10000`) and ask `awk` to sort it by that number.

It is now possible to combine the full pipe-line in a single awk:

```
$ gsutil ls gs://organization-dumps/ambient                                      \
    | awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; FS="."}
           {sub("gs://organization-dumps/ambient/",""); sub("/$","")}
           (NF==0){next}
           {n=split($1,t,"-"); a[t[n]*10000  + t[n-1]*100 + t[n-2]]=$0}
           END {for(i in a) print a[i]}'
```